# In Katalon studio mobile testing i am getting this error while locating one element 'org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException'

Tags: testing, mobile, automation, katalon-studio

Though I have updated the version, the rest of the elements locating properly, in details section it displays the error as `'org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to compile'`

Android studio version 3.5
katalon studio
Version: 6.3.2

Comment: Code where the exception is thrown? I guess one of the selectors has its arguments changed.

Comment: We need some Katalon code to help you.

Comment: When i am trying to click on this object  'androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar$Tab0' is ,it display that error 'org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to compile

Answer (score 0):

I believe this exception is caused by '$' being present in the XPath. I'm not sure but you might need to escape it.

Comment: Where did you see a dollar sign involved in this error ? I'm not saying this is not the right answer but I'm quite curious how you can guess that without more information from the author ?

Comment: The author's comment on Dec 18 mentioned s/he tried to click on: androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar$Tab0